# Risk Assessment of SSH PermitUserEnvironment with ForceCommand

Tags: ssh, security

A dedicated server appliance accepts logins over `ssh` for one login account only which

- is authenticated using public keys only,
- and executes a command configured with `ForceCommand`.

The login account may be used by multiple identities, each having their public key registered in `authorized_keys`.

I want to pass a control token into the command for some of those public keys.

I can use an environment variable for this with the `environment=` setting in `authorized_keys`. To do this, I need to enable `PermitUserEnvironment` which is a **global option** in `sshd_config` (it is not supported in a `Match` block).

By enabling `PermitUserEnvironment`, it also becomes possible for clients to pass environment varables. However, I think this is safe because:

- only variables permitted on the server by `AcceptEnv` settings can be passed by the client.
- variables set in `authorized_keys` take precedence over those passed from a client.
- the only valid login launches a forced command, so there is no way to access an interactive shell where one could tweak the environment.

And I therefore believe that

- Given that I will not use `AcceptEnv`, it should not be possible for a client to pass an environment variable.
- If I set a value to the variable on all public keys then it is impossible for the client to override it, even if (erroeously) permitted by `AcceptEnv`.
- Because there is no shell access, there is no other way for the environment to be modified.

Is this a safe use of `PermitUserEnvironment`, or are there any other risks  that I haven't considered above?